# Not returning picture size, name with french accents

Tags: php, character-encoding

Here's a weird situation...
I have a French language website with informations encoded UFT8 in database.
I use "htmlentities" to properly read and display the info and it works well except this... I need to read the picture size, but i can't get the height and width when i have French characters in title...!

This is the code:

```
$title=mysql_result($result,0,"title");
$title=htmlentities($title);
$title=str_replace(" ","-",$title);
```

.....

```
$im='http://www.website.be/images/'.$title.'-'.$id.'-'.$i.'-l.jpg';
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($im);
```

The images have name like this:
Une-création-architecturale-très-jolie-102-1-l.jpg

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL encode the file name.

```
$im = 'http://www.website.be/images/'.urlencode($title).'-'.$id.'-'.$i.'-l.jpg';
```